# Image properties in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to use the Next.js Image Component in my component for Automatic Image Optimization.

```
import Image from "next/image";

const PicArrs = () => (
  <Image src="remote-location" alt="ViewCrunch" layout="responsive" />
)
```

But I get this error:

**Error: Image with SRC "/renmote-location must use " width" and "height" properties or "unsized" property.**

**NB:** I want the image to take the size of the div, that's why I set it to `layout="responsive"` but when I set height and width which I don't need I won't get this error.

I've read the doc and as stated there I've even set layout to fill and I still get this error even though the doc says you don't need height/width prop if layout is set to fill.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue when I first started playing around with Next's image component.

For the image to be responsive, we need to give the Image component an initial width and height in pixels. The responsive layout will then resize our image down or up depending on the screen size. According to [Next's image docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#device-sizes), the default breakpoints are `deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840]`.

In my case, my parent div's width is 680px, so that's what I used as the width as shown below. However, even if I used 1000px as the width, the Image component would still respect the parent div's width.

```
<Image
  src="/img/cool_cat.png"
  alt="Pretty cool cat"
  width={680}
  height={400}
  layout="responsive"
/>
```

Using the `unsized` property works because we're saying our image doesn't have a size. Next's Image component interrupts this `layout="fill"`, which will not respect the parent div's width leading to unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code;

```
const PicArrs = () => (
       <Image src="remote-location" alt="PedroView" layout="responsive" unsized />
 )
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I no longer get the error, but the image now does not respect height and width of the patent div